# How to draw mesh edges with Threejs

Tags: three.js, webgl, cad, edges

I'm looking at drawing the edges of a mesh like on the following picture:

[image]

I tried to use THREE.EdgesHelper however it only groups the triangles that are in the same plane and therefore it looks like the wireframe on curved areas which I want to avoid.

Ideally it would be some sort of helper that I could display/hide/change colour.

I'm not exactly sure about what to look at for a starting point and your help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Google "gooch shading", "NPR shading". For example http://ar3f.in/goochShading.html and http://ar3f.in/edges_silhouettes.html

Comment: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Outline.html