# Convert 3D model to SVG with Three.js

Tags: svg, 3d, three.js

I'd like to be able to convert fairly complex 3D models to SVG in the browser using [three.js](https://threejs.org/), with the output having one path for each part on the 3D model.

I've tried using the SVG renderer, but it outputs a zillion paths (one per triangle, at least the way I use it) which makes the SVG file unusable.

I'm also exploring Gooch shaders and cel shading - which are above my rookie level, and have tried using `THREE.EdgesGeometry` but I haven't been able to get a decent black line plus white parts output.

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566247/how-to-draw-mesh-edges-with-threejs) and have explored the links in the comments, and I'm exploring the source code to [this three.js example](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Outline.html) to see if it helps.

There are a few pointers out on stackoverflow such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755369/how-to-use-toon-shader-to-convert-3d-models-to-patent-drawings) but they mostly rely on Blender, and I am not sure they'd output SVG.

Any pointers or ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What SVG renderer did you try?

Comment: @Alberto the three.js SVGRenderer at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/renderers/SVGRenderer.js